# Can you append data to a exe file and still keep it executable?

Tags: vb.net, exe, archive

I want to make a self extracting exe file, for this i want to add data to an existing exe file (made in vb.net) that when runt will extract the data that has been appended to it... how can this be done without corrypting the exe file? this needs to be programmed in vb.net ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the idea.  First, you are altering the EXE which means NET may not validate it as legit and if (when) you goof up, you will corrupt the EXE.  Second, in a deployed app your EXE will likely reside in `ProgramFiles` and you will likely not have the ability to open/read/write to thay folder.  Thats just the start, but they are pretty significant hurdles.

You can make a self extracting EXE without appending data to it.  One way, is to stash the data file you need as a resource.  Then the first time you run, extract it and save to one of the several fine existing User folders for AppData.

Comment: A resource is a good idea, but would that not require the data to be added as a resource before the application is compiled? i need it to be a ble to pack user provided data...

Comment: You can put more than ONE file in a self extracting Zip!  Make a zip with the EXE and Data then make it a self extractor.

Comment: I am making an application that can function as a self extracting exe, i am not actually trying to make ONE self extracting zip based on files that i have, i am trying to make an application that can pack and self extract user provided data...

Comment: I am confused by the mixing of WHAT with HOW.  I am trying to figure out what goes in the zip.  Is the EXE you asked about in the original question some sort of main app that USES the data or was it just the code to play the role of EXE in self-extracting EXE.  In the latter case it sounds like you are looking for a hands off data transport mech.